# Using Python RLocks across multiple independent processes

Tags: python, django, celery, python-multiprocessing

I am working on a Django project that uses Celery to schedule some long-term tasks. Both Django and Celery run in completely independent processes and need a way to coordinate access to the database. I'd like to use Python's `multiprocessing.RLock` class (or equivalent) as I need the lock to be reentrant.

My question is, how do I provide access to the RLock for the separate processes?

The two best solutions I've found ([posix_ipc module](http://semanchuk.com/philip/posix_ipc/#platforms) and [fcntl](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html)) are limited to Unix-based systems, and we'd like to avoid restricting ourselves to that.

Is there a cross-platform way to share the locks between processes without having a common ancestor process?

Comment: This is not a direct answer, but unless you need *hard* locking with strong sequentiality, you might want to look at a messaging system such as [0MQ](http://zeromq.org/). A great messaging system that runs on just about anything, and has bindings for just about any language.

Comment: +1 for *0MQ* in order to communicate between process written in various language with a great latency. I am not really used to Celery and what it might already involve (or constrain) but maybe you also could consider to use [`redis`](http://redis.io/topics/distlock), there is already some python bindings around this kind of functionality (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-redis-lock , https://github.com/glasslion/redlock , https://github.com/SPSCommerce/redlock-py , etc.)

Comment: You do realize that this requirement "without having a common ancestor process" means you cannot use `multiprocessing`, right?

Comment: Peter, mgc, thanks for the suggestions! I'll need to look closer to see if those will work.

@Louis, yes. That's the crux of the question. I'm looking for a way to get RLock behavior without a parent process.

Comment: Use the redis lock as suggested by mgc or you could also use the django cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using RabbitMQ as a way to create distributed locks. Details on how to do this can be found on RabbitMQ's blog: https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/02/19/distributed-semaphores-with-rabbitmq/.

In short, you create a RabbitMQ queue for the lock and send a single message to it. To acquire the lock, run a `basic_get` (non-blocking) or `basic_consume` (blocking) on the queue. This removes the message from the queue, preventing other threads from acquiring the lock. Once your work is finished, sending a negative ack will cause RabbitMQ to requeue the message, allowing the next thread to continue.

Unfortunately, this doesn't allow for reentrant locks.

The link referenced above gives Java code for how to go about doing this. Figuring out how to translate this into Python/Pika was annoying enough that I thought I should post some example code here.

To produce the lock:

```
import pika

with pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost')) as connection:
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue="LockQueue")
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='LockQueue', body='Lock')
    channel.close()
```

Acquiring the lock:

```
import pika
import time

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print("Got lock")

    for i in range(5, 0, -1):
        print("Tick {}".format(i))
        time.sleep(1)

    print("Releasing lock")
    ch.basic_nack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
    ch.close()  # Close the channel to continue on with normal processing. Without this, `callback` will continue to request the lock.

with pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost')) as connection:
    channel = connection.channel()

    channel.queue_declare(queue='LockQueue')
    channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
    channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='LockQueue')

    print("Waiting for lock")
    channel.start_consuming()
    print("Task completed")
```